# Adding git commit hash into executable product details does not work for .Net Framework

Tags: .net, git, .net-core, msbuild

It's not a duplicate! I think I tried what I could find in the internet but it didn't help.

I'm using Visual Studio 2022.
I added the following in `Project` element of my .Net Core project's file to add git commit hash into to details of an executable file. And, it worked. But, when I add the same `Target` element into my .Net Framework project it does not add git commit hash.

I tried [this](https://github.com/dasMulli/AssemblyInfoGenerationSdk), but it didn't help. The `Build` button dissapears when I use this custom `AssemblyInfoGenerationSdk`.

Did anyone found a workaround? Is there any other way to add git commit has into to details of an executable file?

```
<Target Name="SetSourceRevisionId" BeforeTargets="InitializeSourceControlInformation">
    <Exec Command="git describe --long --always --dirty --exclude=* --abbrev=8" ConsoleToMSBuild="True" IgnoreExitCode="False">
      <Output PropertyName="SourceRevisionId" TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" />
    </Exec>
</Target>
```

**Projects**

I created a [solution](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UjrKZi8SPmX3_O9hHroI8HtG7nXCUnv-/view?usp=sharing) with 3 projects:

1. **ConsoleApp1_NetCore**: .Net Core project
2. **ConsoleApp2_NetFramework**: .Net Framework project
3. **ConsoleApp3_NetCoreTargetsNetFramework**: .Net Core project but I manually modified the project's file to target .Net Framework 472 (`<TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>`)

The git hash gets generated for projects 1 and 3 since they both have `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`. But, not for project 2 which is not `Sdk` project. The solution with the projects is physically located in a git folder.

Comment: The msbuild `exec` task doesn't change with the target framework. If you run the git command in the directory of your .Net Framework project, what is the result? Is the .Net Framework project in a git repo?

Comment: What do you mean? Here is the post for non-sdk project https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58920312/is-it-possible-to-use-the-microsoft-net-generateassemblyinfo-targets-with-a-non

Comment: Forget about `AssemblyInfoGenerationSdk`. It can't solve your issue. The git commit hash is not an assembly attribute.

Comment: @JonathanDodds, what can I do then?

Comment: The [`Exec` task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/exec-task?view=vs-2022) is a standard task in MSBuild. Its behavior is the same in legacy style .NET Framework projects and SDK style projects.

Comment: You need to understand why is your git command is failing.

Comment: @JonathanDodds, that's why I posted a question here! I have 2 identiacal projects. The only difference is that one of them is .Net Core and the other is .Net Framework. The `Target` element that is in my post works with .Net Core, but not with .Net Framework. I don't have experience with such things so I posted what I tried. Can you post what should I try insted of `Target` element then or do something else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255220/discussion-between-jonathan-dodds-and-theateist).

Comment: I updated my post with solution with 3 projects. The git hash gets generated for projects 1 and 3 since they both have `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`. But, not for project 2 which is not `Sdk` project.

Comment: Your edits provided more detail. You are setting the `SourceRevisionId` property. In an SDK project "If the `$(SourceRevisionId)` property is present, it's appended to `InformationalVersion`." Legacy projects don't have this bit of logic and don't use `$(SourceRevisionId)`.